# Trying to post on mongoDB using mongoose (NODE.JS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the model of the product, where i have the mongoose schema of the object.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

This is my method POST.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = require("../models/product");


      router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
          const product = new Product({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price
          });
          product
            .save()
            .then(result => {
              console.log(result);
              res.status(201).json({
                message: "Handling POST requests to /products",
                createdProduct: result
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500).json({
                error: err
              });
            });
        });
```

**The problem is the following:** whenever i call the method POST on POSTMAN the server never respondes, it gives the error 500 on visual studio code and the server crashes. The body used in POSTMAN is correct and also the connection to the mongoDB is successful.

**The server prints the following error:**

(node:3214) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [node-rest-shop-shard-00-00-pbcph.azure.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to node-rest-shop-shard-00-00-pbcph.azure.mongodb.net:27017 timed out]

(node:3214) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:3214) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: as a general advice, POSTMAN is usually not very reliable, you should really consider start using curl to test Webservices. If you are in Windows, you can use GitBash or LSW.

Comment: `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server` - The application cannot connect to your MongoDB server. This is a networking configuration problem and not related to the code in the question. The unhandled promise rejection calls are because you are calling `mongoose.connect()` without using a `.catch()` or alternately inside a `try..catch` block with async/await. You should fix that code, but the real problem here is networking.

Comment: try to restart your mongodb service by:  sudo service mongod start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem it may that yo don't exporting the router

```
   var express = require('express');

var Product = require('../models/product');

const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/product', (req, res) => {

    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
      });
      product
        .save()
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          res.status(201).json({
            message: "Handling POST requests to /products",
            createdProduct: result
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          });
        });

});


module.exports = router;
```

Try this code i test it in postman.

[Post product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJxZ.png)

Comment: That's not the issue. There is an error message in the question which shows exactly what is wrong. Nothing to do with the code in the question.